# Does  $(this).trigger('click') in jQuery replicate a physical mouse click?

Tags: jquery, onclick, cursor, textarea, mouseover

Would someone out there be able to help me with the following:

I thought $(this).trigger('click') would replicate a physical click made by the user?
Here is the code I have for triggering a click event when moving over a textarea:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var getCursorPos = function(e){
        $(this).trigger('click');
        var $cursor_position = $(this).prop("selectionStart");
        $('#result').html('<p> Cursor position: ' + $cursor_position + '</p>');
        console.log("Auto click at ", $cursor_position, e.pageX, e.pageY);
    };
    $("#text").bind({
        mousemove: getCursorPos,
    });
});
</script>

<html>
    <div id="result"></div>
    <textarea id="text">This is some example text</textarea>
</html>
```

Why does it not return the cursor position from the textarea after triggering the click event.  If I physically press the mouse button, the console readout captures the cursor position.  I thought .trigger('click') would do the same.

How would I fix this code to make it return the cursor position in the textarea as I move the mouse over the textarea?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Martyn

Answer (score 1):

> I thought $(this).trigger('click') would replicate a physical click
>   made by the user?

It does but currently the `this` inside `$(this)` doesn't seem to refer to an element you want to click.

Try creating a button with an `id`, and try this:

```
$('#buttonID').trigger('click');
```

Or simply:

```
$('#buttonID').click();
```

Comment: @Martyn: It was easy but I have created a demo for you to see how it can be done, hope it makes clear now: http://jsbin.com/ojedox/edit#javascript,html. Click the `Render` button there to run code.

Comment: thanks for the demo, I was going to send this which I think is equivalent(?): [url](http://jsfiddle.net/AKeWH/6/)

Comment: @Martyn: Yes it is working fine. You are using `mouseenter` on which it is working fine

Comment: Now if I do something similar: http://jsfiddle.net/fD62H/1/, and be more explicit with the target of the event i.e. `#text`, there still seems to be a difference between coding a trigger event and triggering the event through the user.  The console log reports the `e.pageX` and `e.pageY` as undefined, until the user clicks, even though I'm triggering a `.click()`. Weird right?